# Chip Identification - Electronic sound toy

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I just bought this toy called fridgezoo. It's a small plastic animal that you put in the fridge. It has a light sensor and a button. As soon as there is light, it plays a sound, and when you press the button it plays another sound.

I figured that it may be possible to hack this thing by dumping memory, identify and replace sound content and flash it back onto the device.

There is only a single SOIC-14 chip inside the device, labelled with

NY4P065614
P55101F

There is not much else on the board, just some passives. The chip must contain everything (Storage, amplifier, analog part for light sensor) as there is no other chip on the board.

The thing works with 3 LR44 batteries (so 4.5V).

Do you know how to source some more information about that chip?
What kind of interface (if any) would one expect from such a chip? JTAG?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you won't be able to do any of that.

It's an [OTP](http://b2b.hc360.com/supplyself/348652416.html) (one-time programmable) part that stores 65 seconds of voice, and it has already been programmed.

The programming interface will likely be some kind of simple serial interface that is fairly unique to the device-  not JTAG.

Comment: Thank you for the identification. Thats unfortunate its not reprogrammable, although I almost expectected it to be this way.